# Error al mostrar SnackBar o AlertDialog al regresar de otra pantalla

Tags: listview, flutter

Tengo una interfaz con un `ListView`, cada elemento tiene un `PopupMenuButton` con una opción, dicha opción manda información a otra pantalla

**diseño del widget donde se encuentra el `PopupMenuButton`**

```
class _PruebaPantallaState extends State<PruebaPantalla> {
  int count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("6.-Pantalla prueba");
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: getApidataList(),
    );
  }
  FutureBuilder getApidataList() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: ApiService.getdataList(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          print("3.-Entrada (conexion establecida)");
          final data = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Divider(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.black,
              );
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  data[index]['dataTitulo'].toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(data[index]['dataTextoBiblico'].toString()),
                onTap: () {
                  datadb datadb =
                      datadb("", 0, 0, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0);
                  datadb.setdataId = data[index]["dataId"];
                  datadb.setdataTipo = data[index]["dataTipo"];
                  datadb.setdataNum = data[index]["dataNum"];
                  datadb.setdataNumMasc = data[index]["dataNumMasc"];
                  datadb.setdataTitulo = data[index]["dataTitulo"];
                  datadb.setdataContenido = data[index]["dataContenido"];
                  datadb.setdataPartitura = data[index]["dataPartitura"];
                  datadb.setdataTextPublic =
                      data[index]["dataTextoBiblico"];
                  datadb.setdataDatosPublic =
                      data[index]["dataDatosComplementarios"];
                  datadb.setdataNota = data[index]["dataNota"];
                  datadb.setdataFechaActualizacion =
                      data[index]["dataFechaActualizacion"];
                  datadb.setdataStatus = 1;
                  navigateToDetail(datadb);
                },
                trailing: PopupMenuButton<dynamic>(
                    onSelected: showMenuSelection,
                    itemBuilder: (context) => [
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            child: Text("Agregar a mis listas"),
                            value: data[index],
                          )
                        ]),
              );
            },
            itemCount: data.length,
          );
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }


  void navigateToDetail(datadb data) async {
    bool result =
        await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return dataDetalle(todo: data);
    }));
  }


  void showMenuSelection(dynamic value) async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Play_List(value),
      ),
    );
    if (result) {
      print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Mostrando SnackBar<<<<<<<<<<<<');
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text('Se agrego correctamente a la lista'),
      );
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      print(
          "Se agrego correctamente a la lista--------------------------------");
    }
  }

  void updateListView() {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
    dbFuture.then((databse) {
      Future<List<datadb>> dataListFuture = databaseHelper.getdataList();
      dataListFuture.then((dataList) {
        setState(() {
          this.dataList = dataList;
          this.count = dataList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

---

En esta parte es donde se redirige a otra pantalla

```
trailing: PopupMenuButton<dynamic>(
    onSelected: showMenuSelection,
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
             child: Text("Agregar a mis listas"),
             value: data[index],
          )
    ]),
```

**Metodo `showMenuSelection`**
El cual se supone que al regresar recibe un valor de tipo `bool` para mostrar un `SnackBar`

```
void showMenuSelection(dynamic value) async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Play_List(value),
      ),
    );
    if (result) {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text('Se agrego correctamente a la lista'),
        );
        setState(() {
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        });
    }
}
```

si quito el `setState` me manda la siguiente excepción de la misma manera intente usar un `showDialog` y manda la misma excepción

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart': Failed assertion: line 1184 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.)
```

Si coloco el `setState` me manda la siguiente excepción

> FlutterError (setState() called after dispose():
>   _PruebaPantallaState#d31fe(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted) This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget
>   that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget
>   no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when
>   code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The
>   preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the
>   animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the
>   "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure
>   the object is still in the tree. This error might indicate a memory
>   leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining
>   a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the
>   tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this
>   object during dispose().)

**Para regresar después de agregar a la otra interfaz utilizo el siguiente método**
El metodo contiene mucho mas información pero no creo que sea necesario incluirlo ya que el que regresa a la interfaz es solo una linea.
en caso de que se requiera toda la información, puedo agregarlo.

```
void navigateToDetail(dynamic lista, BuildContext newContext) async {
    Navigator.pop(context,true);
}
```

Comment: agrega el código donde tienes el `showMenuSelection`

Comment: @diegoveloper esta en el trailing que pertenece a un `ListTile` no se si quieres que agregue todo el `ListTitle`

Comment: Me refiero a todo el widget

Comment: @diegoveloper Listo agregue casi toda la clase.

Comment: Y el showMenuSelection de donde saca el context?

Comment: por lo que tengo entendido toma el contexto del `itemBuilder` pero la verdad no lo tengo del todo claro

Comment: y que retornas en este widget: Play_List(value)

Comment: a mi me funciona todo bien, simplemente quita el setState del snackbar, no es necesario

Comment: Quite el `setState` pone en pausa la aplicación y muestra la siguiente excepción `_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart': Failed assertion: line 1184 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.)
`

Comment: es raro, aquí anda todo bien, si pueds poner toda la clase para verificar sería mejor

Comment: @diegoveloper Ya agregue toda la clase, no se si sea relevante pero esta pantalla se muestra a partir de un `Drawer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, este caso es un poco especial, como vez aquí no es necesario usar el método `Builder` para generar un nuevo contexto ya que el `FutureBuilder` ya hace eso (muy aparte de permitirnos trabajar con Futures).

Ahora, el problema es que usas el contexto actual (del FutureBuilder), para mostrar el menu , y luego de seleccionar el menu, te vas hacia otra pantalla, en ese momento, el contexto se perdió y se volvió a generar uno nuevo, pero tu te quedaste con el contexto viejo, por eso el error.

Para solucionar eso vamos a tener que usar `GlobalKey` del `ScaffoldState` para poder obtener la referencia al `Scaffold` actual, y poder mostrar el SnackBar.

Entonces, necesitas hacer estos cambios:

**Agregar una variable que haga referencia al `ScaffoldState`**

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
```

**Asignar esa key al Scaffold**

```
 return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: getApidataList(),
    );
```

**Y finalmente usar esa key para obtener el state del `Scaffold` y mostrar el `SnackBar`**

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: Al dirigirme a esa pantalla de la siguiente forma `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Prueba");` que es usando un `RaisedButton` funciona perfecto lo que me pasaste, pero al utilizar la siguiente forma `return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final bool logged=snapshot.hasData;
          if (logged==true) {
            return Home();
          } else {
            return Inicio_sesion();
          }
        }
      },
    );`

Comment: no entendí lo último

Comment: Resulta que tengo 2 formas de acceder a la pantalla, 1- con un boton que usa una ruta simple (`Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Prueba")`), 
2 - la otra valida si ya inicio sesión el usuario en **Firebase** y dependiendo de si tiene sesión iniciada manda a `Home()` usando lo mencionado anteriormente en caso de no tenga iniciada sesión manda la pantalla `Iniciar_sesion()` y por alguna razon si uso eso no me funciona el `SnackBar`

Comment: manda la siguiente excepción `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: showSnackBar(Instance of 'SnackBar'))`

Comment: eso pasa porque aún no se completa el arbol de widget, si declaras tu método async , y luego generas un delay,  `await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds:300)); ` y luego llamas a `showSnackBar`, debería funcionar

Comment: Realice pruebas y sigue mandando la excepción agregando antes lo que mencionaste y luego la llamada al `showSnackBar` pero no funciona, incluso puse 200 mas al tiempo pero aun a si no.

Comment: sería bueno que crees otra pregunta respecto al streambuilder, ya que me parece un escenario diferente, y la solución que te dí funciona perfectamente para que el código que pusiste en la pregunta

Comment: Ya formule la pregunta especificando lo mas detallado posible como se genera la **excepción**. [Aqui la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/279455/76401)