# Error al mostrar SnackBar utilizando StreamBuilder

Tags: excepciones, flutter

### Mi pantalla inicial

```
class Autentificacion extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Auth auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final bool loggedIn = snapshot.hasData;
          if (loggedIn == true) {
            return Home();
          } else {
            return Inicio_sesion();
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

### Al tener una sesión iniciada manda a la siguiente pantalla Home

La pantalla tiene un `Drawer` con una lista de items
algo similar a lo siguiente

```
int _SelectDrawerItem = 0;
_getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        return PruebaPantalla();
      case 1:
        return Data_List(null);
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    cargarData();
    // print('userId de sharedPreferens =>${userId}');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(titulo),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(...),
      ),
      body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_SelectDrawerItem),
);
```

**Por defecto envia a la `PruebaPantalla()`** la cual contiene una lista de items.

```
    class _PruebaPantallaState extends State<PruebaPantalla> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  int count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("6.-Pantalla prueba");
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: getApidataList(),
    );
  }


  FutureBuilder getApidataList() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: ApiService.getdataList(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          print("3.-Entrada (conexion establecida)");
          final data = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Divider(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.black,
              );
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  data[index]['dataTitulo'].toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(data[index]['dataTextoBiblico'].toString()),
                onTap: () {
                  datadb datadb =
                      datadb("", 0, 0, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0);
                  datadb.setdataId = data[index]["dataId"];
                  datadb.setdataTipo = data[index]["dataTipo"];
                  datadb.setdataNum = data[index]["dataNum"];
                  datadb.setdataNumMasc = data[index]["dataNumMasc"];
                  datadb.setdataTitulo = data[index]["dataTitulo"];
                  datadb.setdataContenido = data[index]["dataContenido"];
                  datadb.setdataPartitura = data[index]["dataPartitura"];
                  datadb.setdataTextPublic =
                      data[index]["dataTextoBiblico"];
                  datadb.setdataDatosPublic =
                      data[index]["dataDatosComplementarios"];
                  datadb.setdataNota = data[index]["dataNota"];
                  datadb.setdataFechaActualizacion =
                      data[index]["dataFechaActualizacion"];
                  datadb.setdataStatus = 1;
                  navigateToDetail(datadb);
                },
                trailing: PopupMenuButton<dynamic>(
                    onSelected: showMenuSelection,
                    itemBuilder: (newContext) => [
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            child: Text("Agregar a mis listas"),
                            value: data[index],
                          )
                        ]),
              );
            },
            itemCount: data.length,
          );
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void navigateToDetail(datadb data) async {
    bool result =
        await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return dataDetalle(todo: data);
    }));
  }

  // Envia a la interfaz Datalist para llevar el data seleccionado
  void showMenuSelection(dynamic value) async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Data_List(value),
      ),
    );
    if (result) {

      SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text('Se agrego correctamente a la Datalist'),
      );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
      print(
          "Se agrego correctamente a la Datalist--------------------------------");
      // _showSnackBar();
    }
  }

  void updateListView() {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
    dbFuture.then((databse) {
      Future<List<datadb>> dataListFuture = databaseHelper.getdataList();
      dataListFuture.then((dataList) {
        setState(() {
          this.dataList = dataList;
          this.count = dataList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

---

Al momento de usar `showMenuSelection` que se encuentra en cada elemento de la lista con un `PopupMenuButton` manda a la interfaz `Data_list`.
En `Data_list` se seleccióna un elemento y se agrega el dato enviado

una ves agregado se utiliza la siguiente linea para regresar un **true** configrmando el haber agregado

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

Regresando a la pantalla `_PruebaPantallaState` para generar el `SnackBar` que se encuentra en el metodo `showMenuSelection` para informar al usuario el resultado
donde me genera una excepción en la siguiente linea

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

La excepcion es la siguiente.

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: showSnackBar(Instance of 'SnackBar'))
```

Comment: Puedes describir mejor el flujo? como empieza todo? hacia donde va? como que pantalla se llama desde el inicio? en que momento se invoca a la linea que te da el error?

Comment: @diegoveloper Modifique toda la pregunta tratando de especificar todo a detalle y quitando cosas tal ves innecesarias

Comment: hey pero tu Scaffold de PruebaPantalla no tiene asignado el `_scaffoldKey` , como lo indiqué en la anterior pregunta, o fue un error tuyo?

Comment: Perdon use una version anterior del codigo en lugar de la nueva.. edito ahorita mismo

Comment: la pantalla Home es Stateless o Stateful

Comment: no logro reproducir el error, si puede ssubir el código a algún repo para intentar reproducirlo te podría ayudar

Comment: @diegoveloper podría agregarte como colaborador usando tu nombre de usuario si me lo puedes proporcionar, ya que tengo los conocimientos basicos sobre Github

Comment: Es igual a este,  'diegoveloper'

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96278/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-richard).

Comment: no dejaste instrucciones de como replicar el flujo de error,  user/pass, a que pantalla ir, que botón presionar ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de revisar tu código, el error es el rebuild de los widgets dentro del `StreamBuilder` esto causa inconsistencias , se pierde el contexto con facilidad.

Te recomiendo repasar bien los conceptos de `StatefulWidget` para que luego pases a revisar algún package/patrón/arquitectura para el manejo de estados, que puede ser 'Provider'.

Para corregirlo, no uses esta validación `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active` , debido a que en cada refresco de widget, el estado del stream siempre pasa de `waiting` a `active`, esto causa un rebuild innecesario de los widgets, lo mejor es hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

Pon un initialData nulo, luego en tu validación haces un `if(snapshot !=null)` para verificar que está cargando.

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
            stream: _auth.onAuthStateChanged,
            initialData: null,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot != null) {
                final bool loggedIn = snapshot.hasData;
                if (loggedIn == true) {
                  return home;
                } else {
                  return sesion;
                }
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          )
```